# unable to connect to HTTPS svn server using svnkit from java app deployed on Heroku

Tags: java, svn, heroku, svnkit

I am using the svnkit to get some information about our svn repository. I used the examples mentioned in the svnkit documentation and I was able to fetch the details when I run the example in my local eclipse. Our repository is accessible via https protocol.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.*;
import org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNDirEntry;
import org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException;
import org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNNodeKind;  
import org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNURL;
import org.tmatesoft.svn.core.auth.ISVNAuthenticationManager; 
import org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepositoryFactory;
import org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.fs.FSRepositoryFactory;
import org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.svn.SVNRepositoryFactoryImpl;
import org.tmatesoft.svn.core.io.SVNRepository;
import org.tmatesoft.svn.core.io.SVNRepositoryFactory;
import org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNWCUtil;

public class HelloWorld extends HttpServlet {
public static String abc="";

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    resp.getWriter().print("Hello from Java! The repository UUID is \n"+ abc);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    Server server = new Server(Integer.valueOf(System.getenv("PORT")));
    ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
    context.setContextPath("/");
    server.setHandler(context);
    context.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new HelloWorld()),"/*");

    //If I use these set I am able to fetch the details from SVN.
//String url = "http://svn.svnkit.com/repos/svnkit/trunk/doc";
  //  String name = "anonymous";
    //String password = "anonymous";

    String url = "https://svn.ourComplanyRepo";
    String name = "username";
    String password = "password";
    long startRevision = 0;
    long endRevision = -1;
DAVRepositoryFactory.setup();
SVNRepository repository = null;
repository = SVNRepositoryFactory.create(SVNURL.parseURIEncoded(url));
ISVNAuthenticationManager authManager = SVNWCUtil.createDefaultAuthenticationManager(name, password);
    repository.setAuthenticationManager(authManager);
    SVNURL XYZ =  repository.getLocation();
    abc = repository.getRepositoryUUID(true); 
    server.start();
    server.join();      
}

}
```

WHen I deployed my code to the heroku, I am running into an issue. When I check the heroku logs this the issue that I found

```
 0m Exception in thread "main" org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E175002: connection refused by the server
```

Could you please help me on how to resolve this?

Answer (score -1):

A [Google-search for the error](https://www.google.com/search?q=org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException%3A+svn%3A+E175002%3A+connection+refused+by+the+server) yields some promising leads, try running with:

```
-Dsvnkit.http.sslProtocols="SSLv3"
```

... as suggested [here](http://issues.tmatesoft.com/issue/SVNKIT-176).

Comment: I wasn't sure on where this statement had to be added. In the forums it was mentioned that this statement needs to be added in Eclispe.ini file, but since I had to deploy the code to Heroku I added this statement to the system.properties file and uploaded to Heroku. But still there's no luck. Heroku logs continue to show the same error message.